# jcrop turns transparent image black

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I would like to use jcrop to select an area on something that has built in javascript which I can't modify. This javascript is interfering with jcrop i think. so I tried putting a transparent gif over the top of the thing I would like to select. This stopped the thing underneath interfering with jcrop and I coudl select areas fine. Jcrop, however, is making the transparent image black rather than transparent.

Here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/andieje/rvTmX/

This is the html

```
         <img id="cropbox" src="http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/demo_files/sago.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px: right: 0px;" />
<img id="transparent" src="http://www.golivetutor.com/download/spacer.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;position: absolute; left: 0px: right: 0px;"/>
```

This just shows a transparent image linked to jcrop and how it becomes black.

Is there any way I could work around this? I dont know much css but I'm not bothered if the modifcation means that the unselected area of the image isn't greyed out anymore - I just want the bounded rectangle around the selected bit.

thanks very much for any help you can give

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because the default option for `bgColor` in jCrop is set to 'black'.

Just add the option for `bgColor` in your init to be nothing and your image will be transparent:

```
 $('#transparent').Jcrop({
    onChange: showCoords,
    bgColor: ''
},function(){
    jcrop_api = this;
});
```

Comment: or set it's opacity like this: `.jcrop-holder { opacity: 0.5; }` http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/rvTmX/5/

Comment: True, but you need to set more opacity parameters for cross browser support. And it is also possible to add the `bgOpacity` option in the init.

Comment: Seems rather well supported: http://caniuse.com/css-opacity but bgOpacity would certainly remove all doubt :)

Comment: bgOpacity in the init does not change the fact that having jcrop on an image with transparent pixels (png) will render a black rectangle

Comment: Using .jcrop-holder { opacity: 0.5; } will change the opacity of the image as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/andieje/rvTmX/)). I changed the image to a div with transparent color by using rgba(0,0,0,0). Let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve.

`<div id="transparent" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;position: absolute; left: 0px: right: 0px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0);"/>`