# Jcrop adds black background to transparent image on render

Tags: jquery, canvas, jcrop

When trying to use Jcrop with a transparent background canvas it renders it in black, I've checked online, and the solution given as per the question on [jcrop turns transparent image black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319594/jcrop-turns-transparent-image-black) doesn't work for me, it still produces a black background. Below is my code.  Any help towards getting this working would be greatly appreciated!

```
var maxWidth = 200;
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = maxWidth;
  canvas.height = img.height * (maxWidth / img.width);

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    document.getElementById('image').src = canvas.toDataURL();

  $('#image').Jcrop({
    bgColor:'',
    setSelect: [0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height]
  });


}
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.src = 'https://z1.porter21.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/02/sprite1.png';
```

A live sample can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/9Lmapguv/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/wepu47zn/

Added thumbnail preview on crop/scale/rotate/etc: http://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/wepu47zn/1/

Added thumbnail preview on crop select and crop/scale/rotate/etc:
http://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/wepu47zn/2/
The on crop select thumbnail in the third link is cropped by a div wrapper with overflow hidden to prevent any need for canvas cropping on every select.

Source: [How should I crop the image at client side using jcrop and upload it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651017/how-should-i-crop-the-image-at-client-side-using-jcrop-and-upload-it/)

See the comment in the `validateImage` function, you can call a method to update a thumbnail image source there. I added `bgColor: ""` which seems to work somehow now to the code too. It also has some transform functions and a submit function (IE10+) thanks to @Tatarize

For submitting cropped images in older browsers see my post at the source.

---

<s>I never got that working either :/</s>

But the cropping output is still a transparent image of course even when it shows black in the cropper.

I used the following "hack" to hide the canvas element with the back background and show a transparent css background image instead.

```
$(".jcrop-active").css({"background": "url(\""+img.src+"\")", "background-size": "100%"});
```

```
.jcrop-active canvas {
    display: none;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/w8bgm8hk/

Comment: Is there a way to implement this also on Jcrops thumbnail preview? As that image appears black. It's not as easy as just setting a background, as it's a zoomed in crop preview.

Comment: I remembered there was a SO question before about Jcrop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651017/how-should-i-crop-the-image-at-client-side-using-jcrop-and-upload-it/. I modified the answer so it doesn't show a black background(bgColor seems to work somehow) and added a comment in the ``validateImage()`` function  to show where you can update the thumbnail image element source: http://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/wepu47zn/